# How to make Entity Framework DbContext generic for dynamic connection string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, moq

This is my method in the business layer:

```
public async task<model> GetMemberList(CancellationToken cancelToken, string connString){
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
             using (var dbContext = DbContext.Create(connString))
                {
                   Code Goes Here....
                }
        }, cancelToken);
      }
      catch
      {
         Throw New Exception(); 
      }
    }
```

we have different clients databases. we pass connString from mvc controller to  business layer methods to initialize new instance of dbContext to connect relevant client database. You can see in my method we used  `DbContext.Create(connString)` to create a connection with database always when this methods run. 
My problem is I can't use moq Framework for unit testing because of this situation. Is there a way to generalize this for dynamic connection string and move dbContext initialization outside the method?

Comment: yes use constructor.

Comment: Would it be an option to pass the connString to the Business class when initializing?

Comment: Take a look at dependency injection there are various frameworks out there to handle this. [Here's a list](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx)

Comment: @Valkyrie can you add a example for this to get a idea. i am new to EF.

Comment: Thank You everyone. got a idea to do it.