# How to use constructor to implement DbContext when have different connection string?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

Here is my method :

```
public async task<model> GetMemberList(CancellationToken cancelToken, string connString)
{
   try
   {
       await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           using (var dbContext = DbContext.Create(connString))
           {
              // Code Goes Here....
           }
       }, cancelToken);
   }
   catch
   {
      Throw New Exception(); 
   }
}
```

In here i used "using" keyword to get dbContext. In every methods I did this because  we have different connection string. I hope this is not a bad way to write methods in entity framwork. I realized this when I was going to write unit test for each methods in the business layer. I want to write a constructor to get dbcontext in generic way. I can use Dependency Injection to do that but i don't know how to do that. Can someone give me a way to do it?

Comment: Are you using .Net core?

Comment: No @AkbarBadhusha.

Comment: What rules do you use to choose connection string? It is possible to configure dependency injection container to inject DbContext with different parameters to different classes as dependency. For example, SomeService will receive dbContext with connString to "someDb" and AnotherService will receive connString to "anotherDb".

Comment: You can create static variables for different connection strings and use it when needed like Singleton pattern. Otherwise if you do not know the connection names, then create a pool and fetch it from it if already present else create new entry in pool

Comment: May I ask what was the intend of your 'await Task.Run(() => ... )' ? I think that is just an unnecessary context switch there

Comment: If you want to use DI for this it's nice to know if you already use some DI framework. But you've made it very unclear what you're actually asking. What's your focus? The constructor logic or DI?

Comment: @GertArnold In here someone told me to use constructor and another one told me to use DI. Thst's why i got confused.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870821/how-to-make-entity-framework-dbcontext-generic-for-dynamic-connection-string

Comment: "someone told me to use constructor and another one told me to use DI". Those are not mutually exclusive. As a matter of fact, Constructor Injection is the _default_ pattern when practicing DI.

Answer (score 1):

Create and Interface IDbFactory

```
public interface IDbFactory
{
    DbContext GetConnection();
}
```

Create a class DbFactory

```
public class DbFactory : IDbFactory
{ 
    public DbContext GetConnection()
    {
        var connectionString = [get this from web.config]
        return new DbContext.Create(connectionString);
    }
}
```

Inject dependacny for IDbFactory in the constructor then

```
public async task<model> GetMemberList(CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
   try
   {
       await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           using (var db = _dbFactory.GetConnection())
           {
              // Code Goes Here....
           }
       }, cancelToken);
   }
   catch
   {
      Throw New Exception(); 
   }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I wrote my methods this way but the problem is how can i do unit test for this type of methods. i can't write mock test for this method. i got stuck in here. I cant use a static dataset. i always have to use database. it's a bad way to do unit test.

Comment: @KSameera, You are using GetMemberList to get member list right? Do you want to send static data set from GetMemberList?

Comment: yes this method to get member list. For the unit test(mocking) i want send static dataset which not coming from database.

Comment: Then you should be using a mock class to provide these details right? I mean, there should be an interface IMemberDetails which will be inherited by both DB class and Mock class. Then you will use instance of Mock class to send details while testing. Right?

Comment: yes i want to use a  instance of Mock class to send details while testing. That's why i need to change my method.

Comment: Then i suggest you create a separate class for mock,add the method with same signature and send mock data from there. Then create an interface that can be used for both Mock class and Original class. Then use the instance as you fit Eg: in MockClass : 
public IMemberDetails _memberDetails =new MemberMockDetails(); 

Eg: in Original: 
public  IMemberDetails _memberDetails   = new MemberDetails();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179011/discussion-between-akbar-badhusha-and-ksameera).

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to hide the logic of building connections string, you can use Factory pattern as it is. In this example building of connection string depends of clientId and is encapsulted in factory. You can mock it as you like in your unit tests for `SomeService`.

```
public class CompositionRoot
{
    private readonly IContainer _root;

    public CompositionRoot()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<SomeService>();
        builder.RegisterType<DbContextFactory>().As<IDbContextFactory>();

        _root = builder.Build();
    }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        return _root.Resolve<T>();
    }
}

public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    DbContext Get(int clientId);
}

public class DbContextFactory : IDbContextFactory
{
    public DbContext Get(int clientId)
    {
        // place here any logic you like to build connection string
        var connection = $"Data Source={clientId}db";
        return new DbContext(new SqlConnection(connection), true);
    }
}

public class SomeService
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory _dbFactory;

    public SomeService(IDbContextFactory dbFactory)
    {
        _dbFactory = dbFactory ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dbFactory));
    }

    public async Task<Model> GetMemberList(CancellationToken cancelToken, int clientId)
    {
        using (var dbContext = _dbFactory.Get(clientId))
        {
            // Code Goes Here....

        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is we use only one service. In the configuration file we can't use connection string this way. we have 30 clients. currently we have dynamic connection string and for these clients we have different databases. according to client we change the connection string.

Comment: How exactly does connection string depend on client?

Comment: Clients have different databases.We create connection with database for the different different client.